# Angular 7 ctor error with FormControlDirective only in AOT build

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-aot

In upgrading from Angular 6 to 7 everything seemed fine except when I output to aot. I can successfully create a build with the cli and one of my lazy loaded modules works and other does not in that it gets a very weird exception.

[image: ctor error]

Putting a breakpoint in this allowed me to find that an array is being passed into the module factory  instead of a constructor. This is what is breaking in aot. 
The culprit is shown below [image: 5 dependencies in array]

However, I cannot figure out how these 5 declarations are being injected, they should only be injected with the ReactiveFormsModule, not on their own. I've simply added them and exported them in a lazy loaded module and they work fine in JIT. Anyone experience a similar issue or find a solution? Code snippet example will follow soon - as I have to reproduce it in public project.

Comment: Is it only Angular 7 issue? Can you also add some relevant code?

Comment: seems to be only Angular 7; I'm still working on a public repoducible case - It's in a company repo now